# How to include an excel file in the build windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an excell file that I need to access via a button in my application. When debugging, I simply have to copy the file to the debug/bin directory and it works with this code:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "estimation 1.xls";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
    }
```

but after building the project, I get a file cannot be found message when pressing the button. I tried including the file by dragging it into the solution manager but it still gives me the error. How can I include this excel file in the build? Will I need to change the code to access it?

[image]

Comment: Check the file in Property inspector, then mark it 'Copy always'.

Comment: Did that but still is a no go.

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the filename.

Comment: can you post an image of your solution explorer that let us see where your xlsx file is ?

Comment: I just edited the post to show the requested image

Comment: When you look at the properties of the excel file in the solution, what is the path? Does the file exist there?

Comment: yes it is. the path is good and I also checked in the folder directly and the file is there.

Comment: Add to resources folder, then change the copy to output directory property to copy, then use  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ( Path.Combine ( Application.StartupPath, "resources", "myExcelFile.xlsx" ));

Comment: @henoc salinas I still get the same file not found when running the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add File to Resources Folder

[image]

2. Change the property "copy to output directory" of file to copy

[image]

3. call with the process.Start, example:

   ```
      public void openFile () {

         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ( Path.Combine ( Application.StartupPath, "Resources", "estimation 1.xls" ));

      }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following if your spreadsheet is in the same directory as your application.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "estimation 1.xls");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
}
```

You will also need to import the System.Windows.Forms namespace at the top of your file.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: Sorry but I just did a new build with the code submitted and i'm still getting that the file cannot be found.

Comment: While this is valid, OP's problem is _"**when building the project**, I get a file cannot be found message"_, not at runtime.

Comment: The error is happening at run time. Not when building the project. I don't get any errors when building it. I get an error after I start the newly built program.

Comment: @ChristianVerner you should edit your question then as it's misleading.